# extundelete does not finish its work

Tags: data-recovery, ext4

I need to restore a file on sda7 so I remounted ro und startet extundelete

```
manuel@P5KC:~/recovery/RECOVERED_FILES$ sudo extundelete --restore-all /dev/sda7
WARNING: Extended attributes are not restored.
Loading filesystem metadata ... 688 groups loaded.
Loading journal descriptors ... 18110 descriptors loaded.
Writing output to directory RECOVERED_FILES/
Searching for recoverable inodes in directory / ... 
1554 recoverable inodes found.
Looking through the directory structure for deleted files ... 
Unable to restore inode 2228446 (lost+found/latex): No data found.
```

But the directory `RECOVERED_FILES` is empty. Am I doing something wrong or is my data lost? Filesystem is ext4. At the end, logged in as su, I am even getting a segmentation fault.

---

Debian Wheezy 3.2.0-4-amd64